# JavaScript sort datatable by a specific column by clicking on header cell of html table

Tags: javascript, sorting

**edited to account for the zero in the sorting logic. It now works on the first row but the rows it sorts seems to be random. Maybe there is a problem accessing the right data from the selection? The row selection structure looks like this:

[image]

I have a table that is drawn according to a list of objects. When I click on the headers of my table, I want to sort the data by that column and then redraw the table. I am using array.sort and I have no errors when I click on the header, use array.sort() or redraw the table, but, it is not sorting the table correctly. It doesn't move the first row values at all and is not sorting as it should. The data element that is used to redraw the table has an array of values that match the header names so I pass the name as 'd' to the sorter function. This is what I have:

```
 sorter(d, i) {

         this.tableElements.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.d > b.d) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a.d < b.d) {
            return -1;
        } else { return 0; }
    });

        console.log(this.tableElements);
        this.updateTable();
```

Any advice would be really helpful!

Comment: Are you able to provide a jsfiddle? Also by [datatable](https://datatables.net/) do you mean this jQuery plugin?

Comment: The sort function should return 1, 0 or -1, not just 1 or -1. If *a* and *b* are equal, then comparing `a, b` and `b, a` will both return 1 (which is a logical impossibility), both should return 0.

Comment: @HaydenPassmore I've never used jsfiddle but could figure it out if that would help. I am not using any jQuery or plugins. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @RobG I updated the function- thanks for the help

Comment: This is a link for [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) it is just a way of running code but it can be shared publicly. But I think @RobG is correct.

Comment: The sort function looks good only. Can you attach the console output of `this.tableElements` before the sort and after the sort to make sure that it's not an issue with sorting.

Comment: @AbhinavJain thanks for the reply. It was a problem with how I was trying to  access the data. I needed to use 'a.value[d]'